# Thinking Sphinx migration without enabled local indexes

Tags: thinking-sphinx, ruby-on-rails-4.2

in migrating from rails 3.2 (where running as per design) to rails 4.2, an application with ThinkingSphinx on 4.2 will run `rebuild`and `restart`, however indexes are not being created with the following error stream

```
using config file '/Users/main/r/saim/config/development.sphinx.conf'...
WARNING: key 'sql_query_info' was permanently removed from Sphinx configuration. Refer to documentation for details.
WARNING: key 'charset_type' was permanently removed from Sphinx configuration. Refer to documentation for details.
WARNING: key 'sql_query_info' was permanently removed from Sphinx configuration. Refer to documentation for details.
WARNING: key 'charset_type' was permanently removed from Sphinx configuration. Refer to documentation for details.
WARNING: key 'sql_query_info' was permanently removed from Sphinx configuration. Refer to documentation for details.
WARNING: 7 more warnings skipped.
indexing index 'azienda_core'...
ERROR: source 'azienda_core_0': unknown type 'pgsql'; skipping.
ERROR: index 'azienda_core': failed to configure some of the sources, will not index.
```

thiking_sphinx.yml  is configured as:

```
development:
  bin_path: /usr/local/bin
  pid_file: /Users/main/r/saim/shared/tmp/searchd.pid
  configuration_file: /Users/main/r/saim/config/development.sphinx.conf
  indices_location: /Users/main/r/saim/shared/sphinx
  use_64_bit: true
#  enable_star: true
  min_infix_len: 2
#  max_matches: 1000
  mysql41: 9313
  mem_limit: 128M
  utf8: true
```

and sphinx.yml (I attempted both with and without spinx.yml in the config folder with identical results)

```
development:
  bin_path: /usr/local/bin
  searchd_file_path: /Users/main/r/saim/shared/sphinx
  use_64_bit: true
  enable_star: 1
  min_infix_len: 1
  max_matches: 10000
  port: 9313
```

installed gems are

```
gem 'mysql2', '0.3.18', :platform => :ruby
gem 'thinking-sphinx', '3.1.2'
```

not sure why pgsql is the hangup...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sphinx is saying it's not configured for PostgreSQL support. Have you re-installed Sphinx recently? And did you explicitly configure for PostgreSQL support when doing so? That's not the default, so you'll need to use the appropriate configuration flag when doing so. I believe it's `--with-postgresql` when using Homebrew, and it's certainly `--with-pgsql` when compiling manually.

Comment: Spot on.  Locally working on a new machine and migrating app to this one.  May I suggest that page http://freelancing-gods.com/thinking-sphinx/common_issues.html (and its siblings) be updated to include this information.  Did these installs yonks ago that I relied on the documentation...  Cheers!